# Coverting localization Date Format

Tags: javascript

```
 result = type == 'date' ? Utils.convertDate2Ansi(input) :
                        type == 'dateTime' ? Utils.convertDate2Ansi(input) + " " + Utils.convertTime2Ansi(input) :
                            Utils.convertTime2Ansi(input);
```

It will give the result as 27-10-2016 i want to convert it into 27/10/2016 we need generic solution

Comment: Too little information to diagnose the problem.

Comment: have you tried momentjs?

Comment: If you just need to change hyphens to forward slashes a simple `.split("-").join("/")` would do it, or you could use `.replace()`. If you want us to help modify your existing `Utils.convertDate2Ansi()` function then you will need to [edit] your question to actually show its code...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). It should be really easy to do this.